# Performing custom bitmap drawing in an iOS application

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios

I am new to iOS/Mac programming. I am trying to create an iOS application that performs custom bitmap drawing, and blits it to screen.

I have looked at some examples that use `CGImage`, but I haven't been able to able to follow them to create an iOS application that performs custom drawing on the application window.

I am now looking for examples/tutorials related to this, written specifically for iOS. Please post any you know of.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of UIView and implement the `drawRect:` method. [Drawing to a Graphics Context in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-SW9)

Drawing a red rectangle:

...with [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
  CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
  CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
}
```

...with [UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  [[UIColor redColor] set];
  CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
  UIRectFill(rectangle); 
}
```